# How to wire a solid state relay according to code

Tags: electrical, code-compliance

I want to build an outlet that I can control on a timer or through a device like a smartphone. I am planning on using a solid state relay for this job. I'm aware of the electrical code stipulation that all low voltage and high voltage wires must be separated by a permanent barrier, as explained [in this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/15553/how-can-high-and-low-voltage-be-mixed-in-a-junction-box?newreg=8bae0f41eae84181815a7740f1f74666). I was going to use a double gang box from home depot like [this one](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Madison-Electric-Products-Smart-Box-2-Gang-Multi-Mount-Adjustable-Depth-Device-Box-MSBMMT2G/203343443?MERCH=REC-_-PIPHorizontal1_rr-_-202077335-_-203343443-_-N) to accomplish this. My question is, with the separator there, how do I connect the relay to the low voltage control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mix Class 2 conductors with power conductors in boxes if the power circuit conductors are introduced solely to connect to the equipment connected to the Class 2 circuit.

Class 2 circuits voltage and current limits are well-defined by National Electrical Code (NEC.) Also, NEC defines spacing between the class 2 conductors and power inductors.

See NEC article 725 for more.

Comment: Let's say someone has a 5VDC microcontroller driving the 5VDC control line of solid-state relay that switches on/off 240V/5A to drive the coil of a remote contactor. The microcontroller is powered with 9-12VDC (regulated down to 5VDC onboard).  Does that mean that #12 wires @ 240V/5A can be brought the *same* junction box area that has the 9VDC-12VDC powered microcontroller and also the 5VDC triggered solid state relay, so that the solid state relay switch the 240V on/off?